# What is the correct command for performing a git-rebase in this scenario?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm still getting my head around using git-rebase, and I'd like to double check what I'm planning on doing before I actually do it!

The relevant branches in my repo currently look like this:

```
o---o---o......   master
         \
          o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o   develop
                   \
                    o---o   feature
                         \
                          *   sub-feature
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
o---o---o......   master
         \
          o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o   develop
                                           \
                                            o'---o'   feature
                                                  \
                                                   *   sub-feature
```

I'm not expecting any conflicts, as the `feature` branch is only deleting files that are no longer required, and the `sub-feature` branch has added new files which definitely don't exist on the `develop` branch.

Based on the [git-rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), I think I need to runthe following from the `sub-feature` branch:

```
git rebase feature
```

I'm a little unsure though, because I want to rebase on to `develop` and not `master`. With this in mind, I'm wondering if should instead run the following from the `sub-feature` branch:

```
git rebase --onto develop feature
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onto` is very powerful, but since you are still getting used to rebasing, and this operation will require two steps regardless (assuming you want to update both `feature` as well as `sub-feature`) I would recommend these steps:

First let's update `feature`:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase develop
```

Finally, update `sub-feature`:

```
git checkout sub-feature
git rebase feature
```

This will leave you with the tree you stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm curious to know what happens to the `sub-feature` branch after doing `git checkout feature` followed by `git rebase develop`. As the `sub-feature` branch was created from the `feature` branch, would that not automatically be "moved" when `feature` is rebased? If not, is the `sub-feature` branch in limbo until it's also rebased?

Comment: @MattElkins What a rebase is really doing is creating a branch new commit (the o' in your diagrams) that has the same content as the previous commit (barring conflicts) but just a different parent. So after _develop_ is rebased on _feature_ the _sub-feature_ branch pointer actually remains unchanged. It's still pointing to the commit that _develop_ previously pointed to (so o rather than o'). There is no auto-moving. So, I suppose you could say it's in "limbo" until you additionally rebase _sub-feature_ on to the newly updated _feature_ branch pointer.

Comment: I emphasize "branch pointer" here because it's important to note that the existing commits themselves are not changing at all...the rebase operation is simply creating new commits and updating the branch pointers

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes perfect sense. I've just followed the steps form your original post in my repo and it worked flawlessly! Thanks for your help!